# Unmarshalling query params into object using Swagger/Springfox and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I've got a search endpoint in my REST service. I'm using Spring Boot, so I've got a @RestController setup with a method that returns search results based on a search query. This is the method definition:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Get global search results")
@RequestMapping(method = GET, produces = {"application/json"})
public SearchResults get(SearchQuery query) {
    ...
}
```

I was hoping that SwaggerUI would show the SearchQuery's fields as separate query params in the ui. It doesn't; it just shows a generic "query" param. If I annotate query with @RequestBody the user can add a json payload to the body, but this is a GET request - I want the user to only use query params.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate `SearchQuery` with `@ModelAttribute` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Well, that was easy. Very nice. Thanks, brother.

Comment: It does not work for me with Srpring 2.6.3 and springdoc 1.6.6...

Answer (score 2):

For Srpring 2.6.3 and springdoc 1.6.6 works with `@ParameterObject` annotation before `SearchQuery`